# Generate empty li elements when there is no post

Tags: php, wordpress

in wordpress I have a loop that returns the 8 most recent posts. What I want to do is, even when the post number is lower than 4, there must be always 4 list elements (in case there is no post, empity li elements).
For exemple, page has only two posts, the loop needs to generate 2 empity li. If the page has 4 of more posts, no empity li must be generated. 
Whith the present code, its generating more than 4 li.

```
<ul class="slider sp">
        <?php
        $ids = get_field('related', false, false);
        $query_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 8,
            'post__in' => $ids,
            'orderby' => 'post__in',
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
        $count = $query->post_count;
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $thumbnail = get_field('image0');
        if(empty($thumbnail)){ $thumbnail = APP_URL . "images/cms/no-image.png"; $borderclass = "hasborder";}
        ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="imager">
                        <div class="img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>);"></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="ttl">
                    <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
                    </p>
                    <p class="price"><?php echo the_field('a-price'); ?>円（税別）</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile;
            $count = 4 - $count;
            if($count > 0){
               for( $i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++){echo '<li></li>';}} endif; ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Small bug: ```for( $i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)``` Should be just ``` $i < $count```

Comment: Could you writer your comment as an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor bug: for( $i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) Should be just `$i < $count`

Or

```
//$count = 4 - $count;
for( $i = $count; $i < 4; $i++)
```

Both will work correct

Comment: for( $i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++) it did work when there are 3 post, but for the rest didnt work

Comment: if($count > 0){
for( $i = $count; $i < 4; $i++){echo '<li></li>';}} endif; ?> like this?

Comment: @FernandoSouza YES and note that you generate empty <li> that will look different than the above full blown <li> tags

Comment: @FernandoSouza You do not need the ```if($count > 0)``` at the beginning!

Comment: It oly works when I have 3 post. If 2 or 1, it looks bugy.

Comment: @FernandoSouza You need to put something like ```<li><div class="filler"></div></li>``` and class "filler" will have width & height to flll the empty area.
This is instead of empty <li>

Comment: I am really sorry for the inconvenient, found the problem here: as I am using a slider plugin, I had to use !important to keep the li size to fix it.

Comment: @FernandoSouza NO problem at all. Glad you fixed it!